# Screenshot with canvas

Tags: javascript, html5

estoy tratando de realizar una captura de pantalla con canvas, consigo realizar la captura, pero quiero conseguir hacer la captura de un div específico de un formulario ya que no me interesa capturar toda la web ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```js
    <script>
        function getScreen() {
            var caption = $('#caption-input').val();
            $("#caption-text").html(caption);
            $("#panel").hide();
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                dpi: 192,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    $("#blank").attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                    $("#blank").attr('download', caption + '.png');
                    $("#blank")[0].click();
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
```

```html
            <div id="caption-input" class="relative pastilla"> /* Esto es lo que quiero capturar solo */
                <div>
                    <i class="icon_ash2"></i>
                </div> 
                <div class="container centrado_centrado">

                    <?php echo do_shortcode($shortcode); ?>
                </div>
                

            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

en vez de pasarle `document.body` como primer parámetro a html2canvas pásale el nodo que quieres capturar.

```
html2canvas($('#caption-input'), { ... })
```

**EDIT** Por si alguien en el futuro ve esta respuesta, probablemente no le va a funcionar porque:

1. La versión estable actual de HTML2Canvas acepta un selector de jQuery como dije arriba, pero la versión 1.0.0 que hoy está en versión alpha, requiere que sea un nodo del DOM. Por lo tanto se debe usar:

ya sea

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('caption-input'), { ... })
```

o bien

```
html2canvas($('#caption-input')[0], { ... })
```

2. El uso de un callback `onrendered` también [está descontinuado](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/blob/0fe9632a32f6a6bede908f393f3f1e22094d290c/CHANGELOG.md#v100-alpha1---5122017). Lo correcto es usar la salida de `html2canvas(elemento,options)` como una promesa.

Por ejemplo:

```
html2canvas(jQuery('#caption-input')[0], {...options...})
.then(function(canvas) {
    $("#blank").attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
});
```

Sin embargo, en el ejemplo siguiente no puedo mostrar ese cambio porque estoy usando el último paquete estable publicado que es la versión `0.4.0`. (Pueden ver [el ejemplo en Plunkr corriendo con la versión 1.0.0-alpha de HTML2Canvas](https://plnkr.co/edit/XOhmtx?p=preview))

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('#capturar').on('click', function() {
        html2canvas(jQuery('#caption-input')[0], {
                dpi: 192,
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    $("#preview").attr('src', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                    $("#blank").attr('href', canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                    $("#blank").attr('download', 'captura.png');
                    $("#blank")[0].click();
                }
            });
      });
    });
```

```css
.row {
      margin-top:10px;
      border:1px solid;
    }
    .pastilla {
      border: 2px solid red;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 4px auto;
      text-align:center;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap.js@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.0/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-6">HOLA SOY UN TEXTO QUE NO SE VA A CAPTURAR</div>
          
          <div class="col-xs-6"><button class="btn btn-info" id="capturar">Capturar el div de abajo</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       
       <div class="col-xs-12">
      <div id="caption-input" class="relative pastilla">
                <div>
                   <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                </div> 
                <div class="container centrado_centrado">

                    AQUI VA UN TEXTO CUALQUIERA QUE QUIERO CAPTURAR
                </div>
                

            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="text-align:center">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      AQUI IRÁ LA IMAGEN CAPTURADA
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <img src="" id="preview">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
      <a class="btn btn-success" href="" id="blank">Descargar</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Solo tenia que añadir este codigo html2canvas($("#caption-input"),

Comment: Hola Antonio Ángel, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Trata de editarla para añadir algo más de información: ¿dónde iría ese código? ¿por qué funcionaría en lugar de lo que ya tenías? Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.

Comment: Ojo que eso no funciona en la versión 1.0.0 de HTML2Canvas. Cuando salga la versión estable voy a modificar mi respuesta para mostrar a conciencia cómo debe hacerse.

Comment: Antonio, deberias quitar esta publicacion ya que es lo que te comenta @Amenadiel en su respuesta. Si te sirvió considera marcarla como aceptada. Un saludo